# how to return bmp format for get Request?

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, rgb

@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
This have only 3 types: GIF, PNG, JPEG. For bmp returns just black pixels.
How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify media type for BMP images.
According to RFC standart, the media type for bmp images is `"image/bmp"`
RFC standart:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7903.html
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image

`MediaType` class contain just a few string constants. You can extend it according to RFC. Also you can define any custom media type string in `produces` tag.

```
@GetMapping(
        value = "/{id}",
        produces = "image/bmp"
)
public @ResponseBody
byte[] getImage(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws IOException {

}
```